# Decode unicode character representation from scraped JavaScript text using Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, unicode

I'm using a web crawler (written in Scala) to get some content from various websites and I have to decode a unicode notation from a JavaScript snippet

```
Capitali%20d%u2019Europa
```

must be decoded as

```
Capitali d’Europa
```

But I cannot find a right tool to do it.

Comment: This is the weird encoding that comes out of the JavaScript `escape()` function. It looks a bit like URL-encoding but is not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that.

```
def unicodeDecode(str: String): String = {
  val parts = """%u\d{4}|%\d\d|[^%]+""".r.findAllIn(str).map(s =>
    if(s.startsWith("%")) {
      Integer.parseInt(
        (if(s.startsWith("%u")) s.substring(2, s.size)
         else s.substring(1)), 16).toChar.toString
  } else s)
  parts.mkString
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! But notice there was a bug in the regular expression: you didn't handle correctly the hexadecimal notation. I fixed it.